# Why there is no PopUp for TextBox with InputScope is Number

Tags: winrt-xaml

Hi I am Using VS2012 for Win8 for WinRT app development. I had tried the InputScope for textbox. 
When I run the app in Emulator, there is no PopUp Number like Wp to select when textbox is clicked. Did I miss anything?

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="38" Text="" InputScope="Number" Height="60" Width="103" Margin="100,10,0,10" />
```

Thanks

Comment: [Working fine for me](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/264/kvnh.png), which keyboard type are you getting ? What do you mean by `Popup` ?

Comment: Thanks. The PopUp Panel is what I mean the On-Screen Keyboard just like your screenshot. I run the WinRT App in Emulator or Simulator in VS2012, there is no response when I clicked the textbox as described above. Can you tell it is correct. What you did to bring up the On- Screen keyboard. Please show the code. Thanks

Comment: I used the code exactly what you posted. Did you select [touch mode](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/9868/jj1b.png) in simulator ?

Comment: Thank you so much for this important picture. Now, the problem is solved.

Comment: I am adding that as answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test `InputScope` property of textbox with on-screen keyboard, the app needs to be open in simulator with touch mode selected.

[image]